# Python - Conditionals based around character location within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that I'm using to pull values. I'm using letters as keys with values dependent on the letter location within the string.

I'm trying to code it so that as the letter is found within the string, it pulls the value that is accurate for its position within the string. I have 3 locations - "starter" and "finisher" are the first and last 4 characters respectively. Anything else is "mid".

I've tried getting the character's position within the string to be taken as an integer that I can easily input into a conditional sequence.

```
def Calc(letterstring, data_table):
    Places= len(string)
    Score = 0.0

    for i in range(Places): 
        letter= string[i] 
        if [i] >= int(3) and [i] <= ((Places)-4):
            position_in_string = "Starter"
        elseif [i] >= ((Places)-4):
            position_in_string = "Finisher" 
        else:
            position_in_string = "Mid" 

        position = (position_in_string) 

        Score += data_table[letter][position] 

    return Score

string = input("Insert your line here: ") # Something like ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
total_score= (Calc((string), (data_table)))
print (total_score)
```

And I would expect an output of an integer.

But if I try to do it this way, I end up with:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: list() >= int()
```

Any advice or observations would be welcome!

Comment: Can you show an example input and what your desired output is? It is unclear from your description what you are trying to do.

Comment: replace the `[i]` to `i` in your loop.

Comment: What is `data_table` supposed to be, a `dict`? And if yes what would a example `data_table` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes I'd recommend:

1. Python has an enumerate builtin that will take a sequence (including a string) and return both the index and the value for each element in the sequence
2. Use letterstring consistently in your function, and in general, using "string" as a variable name is frowned upon
3. I'm assuming data_table is a dict of dictionaries, such that the outer dictionary has keys = to 'A-Z' (note the .upper() to ensure that 'a' gets converted to 'A' etc.  You should probably also add some error checking in case a user puts in ABC1), and the inner dictionary has the 3 strings you set (Starter, Finisher, and Mid)

`no idea why this is getting dorked up formatting`

```
    def Calc(letterstring, data_table):
    Score = 0.0
    ls = len(letterstring)
    for i,letter in enumerate(letterstring):
        if i < 4:
            position_in_string = "Starter"
        elif i >= (ls-4):
            position_in_string = "Finisher" 
        else:
            position_in_string = "Mid" 

        Score += data_table[letter][position_in_string] 

    return Score

instring = input("Insert your line here: ") # Something like ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
total_score= Calc(instring.upper(), data_table)
print (total_score)
```

Comment: Thank you. The answer from luoluo and yourself helped greatly.